# Yii, YiiMongoDbSuite and Labels in CActiveForm with an embedded Document Structure

Tags: mongodb, model, yii, yii-extensions

I've created a model `Users` plus a corresponding model `UsersPrefs` which handles embedded documents under `Users`. This is the preferred and documented way of doing embedded documents with YiiMongoDbSuite.

Now I've created a form for updating those embedded `UserPrefs` by creating a `Users` model.
Problem: The labels for `UsersPrefs` as described in `public function attributeLabels()` are not available in the `Users` Obeject, and so using CActiveForm (e.g. `$form->label($model->MAIL);`) in the corresponding view fails with `Property Users.MAIL is not defined`.

How can I make use of those labels in the embedded document model?

Answer (score 0):

When defining embedded documents like (assuming UsersPrefs have field MAIL, and attributeNames method)

```
public function embeddedDocuments()
{
    return array(
        'prefs' => 'UsersPrefs',
    );
}
```

You should be able to use this in form

```
$form->label($model->prefs, 'MAIL')
```